How to keep \n in encrypting with python?
In this simple code when I give it a text file, the program encrypts it and decrypts it afterwards, the question is why the line if ch != '\n' doesn't work and '\n's are all ignored when the file is decrypted?
# Encryption 
file_location = input('Enter the loaction of your text file: ')

def encrypt_file(paragraphs: list):
output = ''

for ph in paragraphs:
    for ch in ph:
        ASCII_of_ch = ord(ch)
        ASCII_of_ch = int((ASCII_of_ch + 5))
        output += chr(ASCII_of_ch)
        
    return output

with open(file_location, 'r+', encoding='UTF-8') as text_file:
    text_paragraphs = text_file.readlines()
    enc_text = encrypt_file(text_paragraphs)

    text_file.seek(0)
    text_file.write(enc_text)
    print('Done!!')



# Decryption
file_location = input('Enter the loaction of your encrypted file: ')

def decrypt_file(text: str):
   output = ''

    for ch in text:
        ASCII_of_ch = ord(ch)
        ASCII_of_ch = int((ASCII_of_ch - 5))
        output += chr(ASCII_of_ch)
        
    return output

with open(file_location, 'r+', encoding='UTF-8') as text_file:
    file_text = text_file.read()
    enc_text = decrypt_file(file_text)

    text_file.seek(0)
    text_file.write(enc_text)
    print('Done!!')

When I write:

Hi


How are you?


What's up?

after decryption it becomes:

Hi How are you? What's up?


@jasonharper thank you I just understood the problem, any suggestions to solve it?

There's no reason to split the file into paragraphs to begin with. Just encrypt text_file.read() directly.

You seem to have two encrypt_file defined. Was one of them supposed to be decrypt_file?

@JonSG Yes you're right, forgot to change the name.

@chepner You're right, I wanted to progress the file paragraph by paragraph to reduce memory usage, but seems like my approach wasn't useful.  Any idea how to do it? If I prosses the file paragraph by paragraph and save the result in a separate file it'll work, won't it?

The memory was used as soon as you executed text_file.read(). If you want to iterate over paragraphs instead of lines, you'll have to write your own iterator that reads the file line-by-line until encountering an empty line, at which point it yields the lines read so far as a single string of some kind.

@chepner Really appreciate it, thanks.

You are splitting your file by \n, which means that it will remove all \n's. Also you have a with open block twice in your code for some reason and it's not clear why.
Here is a more efficient rewrite of your code.
file_location = input('Enter the location of your text file: ')

with open(file_location, 'r+', encoding='UTF-8') as text_file:
    text = text_file.read()
    output = ""
    for ch in text:
        if ch != "\n":
            ch_ascii = ord(ch)
            output += chr(ch_ascii - 5)
        else:
            output += "\n"

print(output)


Thank you so much, I did it because I wanted to progress the file paragraph by paragraph to reduce memory usage, but seems like my approach wasn't useful. Any idea how to do it? If I prosses the file paragraph by paragraph and save the result in a separate file it'll work, won't it?

You have to make some changes in encrypt_file(paragraphs: list) function. Because when you are trying to split your text using text_file.read().split('\n') \n is removed from it.
Now my suggestion is that create an output variable that will store encrypted text for each line and when encryption of one line is completed append the encrypted text to a list and clear output variable. Repeat this process for all the lines, and at the end, you can join the whole list using \n to return encrypted text with \n.
Here is corrected version of the function:
def encrypt_file(paragraphs: list):
    encrypted_list = []
    
    for ph in paragraphs:
        output = ''
        for ch in ph:
            if ch != '\n':
                ASCII_of_ch = ord(ch)
                ASCII_of_ch = int((ASCII_of_ch + 5))
                output += chr(ASCII_of_ch)
            else:
                output += ch
        encrypted_list.append(output)
    enc_text = '\n'.join(encrypted_list)
    return enc_text

